# Why am I getting TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None when trying to parse JSON data from a file to another?

Tags: json, python-3.x, file

I have this code in python

```
keys = input('Enter the keys you want to extract separated by commas: ').split(',')


def extract_key_value(key):
    with open(output, "w") as f:
        with open(locationJSON, "r") as fi:
            data = json.loads(fi.read())
            final_key = json.dumps(key)
            value = data.get(str(final_key))
            
        f.write(value)
```

I am trying to extract from a large JSON file some specific keys and values so I can convert those values into a CSV file later.

Please help

TYSM

I tried different ways, I even asked chatGPT and Bard for guidenance, but I wasn't able to extract the keys and values in JSON format nor extract them at all.

I expect an output JSON file like this

```
[
{
"key":"value",

},
{
"key":"value"
},
...
]
```

What I want to achieve is to get the pair of keys and values from the loacationJSON file and write them into the output file as a JSON. Then I will convert them into a CSV files for analytic purposes. I have to mention that the locationJSON file contains objects inside the object, and there are values I need to extract from there also.

I tried the debugging and look where I messed up. Found it, but still getting the same error. I read the json library docs. But couldn't find the solution to it.

Also, I've been syncing up with a friend that also codes, but both of us were so lost that none of us could find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

the error message is pretty self-explanatory - the value of variable `value` is `None`. You can check that by adding `print(value)` to your code.

the error is most likely caused by following line:

```
final_key = json.dumps(key)
```

so whatever you put there is serialized to json:

```
In [1]: json.dumps('foo')
Out[1]: '"foo"'
```

So what I assume you want to do is this instead:

```
value = data.get(str(key))
```

My advice - add a lot of `print()` along the way and then you'll be able to determine where it goes wrong.

Unrelated suggestion - when you are loading json from file, you can use `json.load(fi)` instead if reading the whole content into a string and then loading the string via `json.loads()`:

```
with open(locationJSON, "r") as fi:
    data = json.load(fi)
```

Comment: I tried to do that, it sends this 

´ File "path/to/file", line 18, in extract_key_value
    f.write(value)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None´